# Использование NSCollectionView без байндингов

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, macos

Весь интернет перерыл, но так и не нашел примера использования NSCollectionView без байндингов и Array Controller. Может кто-то встречал? Направьте на истинный путь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ здесь на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660626/how-to-create-nscollectionview-programatically-from-scratch). В ответе пример который строит NSCollectionView на весь размер окна и добавляет массив кнопок-итемов. Т.е. вместо кнопок можно вцепить свой NSView с компонентами.